# Control manifest meta-data from gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

I need to build two versions of Android appplication - one for testers (developer mode on) and one for users (developer mode off). How to do that ? Now i have meta-data value in manifest and i use it in code, but have to manually change this value before make build. Is possible to change this by gradle ?

manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="developer.mode" android:value="true" />
```

code

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;

    ...

    private void loadMetaData() {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = ctx.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            DEVELOPER_MODE = ai.metaData.getBoolean("developer.mode");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
}

...

if(App.DEVELOPER_MODE) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common case to have such switch. You can do it with meta tags and manifest merger, but I think most of the developers are using `BuildConfig` for this purpose. You can extend it with your own values:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_MODE", "true"
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_MODE", "false"
        }
}
```

Or check the default ones which are already provided by android gradle plugin.

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.stackoverflow.question.debug";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "flavor1";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "v1.0.1";
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final boolean DEV_MODE = true;
}
```

You can then reference this values from applications java code

```
if (BuildConfig.DEV_MODE) {
   // do developer things
}
```

`BuildConfig` is autogenerated file which will be recreated on each build variant assemble task.